# JavaScript function parseFloat() fails for negative values in certain locales

Tags: javascript, angular

While working with locale translation and parsing decimal numbers from text to numerical values in Angular 10, I came across the following problem:

Consider the string value `value = "-35.17 %"`. I want to convert this a numerical value using `parseFloat(value)`. This works fine for application locale en-US.

However, if the user changes application locale to nb-NO (Norwegian), the parsing fails, resulting in a `NaN`.

The reason for this is that the Norwegian locale uses a different character for the negative prefix (− instead of -).

The workaround for this particular issue is simple, by performing a `.replace("−", "-")` on the string before parsing, but shouldn't JavaScript be able to handle parsing of both these characters? Is it only safe to perform parsing on locale en-US?

Comment: The rules for `parseFloat()` are that the string has to be a **valid JavaScript numeric constant**.  The syntax of JavaScript does not vary by locale.

Comment: Generally you shouldn’t parsefloat a localized string, because thousands separator and decimal point/comma can vary and parsefloat expects only period for decimals, and clearly a minus sign not a (thing that you have) for negatives.

Comment: I would be concerned with other negative formats as well.  Some places surround positive numbers with parentheses to denote negative.

Comment: So the string should not be localized, and if that can't be avoided it must be "cleaned" before performing a parsefloat. I have no idea why nb-NO isn't using a regular minus character, I think it's Angular converting it when changing the locale. Thanks for sharing your views. John is right, parentheses will be a problem as well. Probably best off using a regex to extract a compatible substring, in combination with replace()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JavaScript function `parseFloat()` needs an input string that meets certain requirements, including (but not limited to) the following:

- If parseFloat encounters a character other than a plus sign (+), minus sign (- U+002D HYPHEN-MINUS), numeral (0–9), decimal point (.), or exponent (e or E), it returns the value up to that character, ignoring the invalid character and characters following it.

Localized strings may contain characters that does not meet those requirements.